# Particle Swarm Optimization implementation in mathematica

Tags: algorithm

Hi I am new to mathematica, I want to use it to implement PSO instead of using matlab. Could anyone suggest me how to find some implementation examples with code or its general implementation for reference.

Comment: possible links [Particle Swarm Optimization: An Exploration Kit for Evolutionary Optimization](https://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Conferences/6039/) and [Particle Swarm Optimization for 2D Problems](https://demonstrations.wolfram.com/ParticleSwarmOptimizationFor2DProblems/) and [Particle Swarm Optimization for 1D Problems](https://demonstrations.wolfram.com/ParticleSwarmOptimizationFor1DProblems/) and [The Mathematica Journal](https://www.mathematica-journal.com/2010/02/05/exploratory-toolkit-for-evolutionary-and-swarm-based-optimization/)

Comment: Is it possible to see the source code of this implementation https://demonstrations.wolfram.com/ParticleSwarmOptimizationFor2DProblems/

Comment: Yes. The source code is right there on the page. You can download the notebook and look at it.